# How to map all address fields into one MailChimp address field with Elementor form?

Tags: mailchimp, elementor

Website redesign (original designer MIA), existing MailChimp account. I have a form built with Elementor and it is connected correctly with API key. Name and Email map correctly and populate MailChimp.

Problem is my Elementor form has fields for Address / City / State / Zip / Country, but MailChimp has only an Address column with all of these combined. In Field Mapping on the Elementor form, I can only select one of my Elementor form fields to map to the Mailchimp address.

Even when I map just the address field (text field) it doesn't populate the address column in MailChip, so I suspect Mailchimp is expecting something specific, but I don't know what.

What step am I missing?

I tested a MailChimp embed form (html) on a hidden page and it worked correctly, but I want the functionality of Elementor as it collects responses and can send notification emails from the form.